# I am trying to fit multiple distributions to my data in R, but can't find out how to do that. Can anyone help me?

Tags: r, distributions, aic, curve-fitting

I'm doing research on plastic pollution in urban areas. The data represents the amount of plastics for certain segments. To get uniform data, the data is divided by the area where the plastic is found, which results in a continuous data set. My goal is to make a classification system that makes it easier for policy makers and stakeholders to interpret the degree of plastic pollution. The boundary values for the different classes should be determined by a "cumulative relative frequency graph", which is made using a density curve (and therefore I need the right distribution for my data).

This is the data that I want to find the best distribution for:

> s_all_data

```
  [1] 0.000000000 0.000342466 0.000714286 0.001027397 0.001027397 0.001425720 0.001428571 0.001547988 0.001625450
 [10] 0.001666667 0.001675978 0.001675978 0.001996008 0.002063983 0.002096436 0.002096436 0.002142857 0.002279635
 [19] 0.002281152 0.002945302 0.003072626 0.003250900 0.003287982 0.003397825 0.003424658 0.003462604 0.003611971
 [28] 0.003636364 0.003892944 0.003904725 0.004000000 0.004363636 0.004385965 0.004411935 0.004558824 0.004628331
 [37] 0.004643963 0.004644809 0.004685670 0.004796930 0.004800000 0.004857143 0.004857143 0.005000000 0.005076142
 [46] 0.005116959 0.005151515 0.005294118 0.005329593 0.005432099 0.005464481 0.005503145 0.005596212 0.005668016
 [55] 0.005714286 0.005967337 0.006000000 0.006009070 0.006010929 0.006029412 0.006079027 0.006349206 0.006349206
 [64] 0.006400000 0.006578947 0.006700168 0.006727273 0.006890612 0.006913580 0.006913580 0.006933333 0.007156048
 [73] 0.007195395 0.007299270 0.007533362 0.007878788 0.008040936 0.008049887 0.008097166 0.008394318 0.008759124
 [82] 0.008793970 0.009171908 0.009188034 0.009393988 0.009474591 0.009523810 0.009836066 0.010893855 0.011055276
 [91] 0.011306533 0.011330409 0.011360449 0.011390285 0.011791383 0.011838140 0.012234534 0.012539185 0.012546336
[100] 0.012876884 0.013030303 0.013580247 0.014102564 0.014529915 0.014740369 0.014837954 0.014965986 0.016025641
[109] 0.017066667 0.017090909 0.017226529 0.018949182 0.020924574 0.029554656 0.030395137 0.031174089
```

I have made a Cullen and Frey graph with this data that looks like this:
[image: Cullen and Frey graph]

I thought that possible distributions according to this graph might be: gamma, lognormal, exponential, beta and Weibull.

So now I want to fit these distributions to my data using the fitdist function in R. Until now this is the code I have:

```
fit.normal <- fitdist(s_all_data, distr = "norm")
plot(fit.normal)

fit.gamma <- fitdist(s_all_data, distr = "gamma")
plot(fit.gamma)

fit.exponential <- fitdist(s_all_data, distr = "exponential" )
plot(fit.exponential)

fit.lognormal <- fitdist(s_all_data, distr = "lnorm")
plot(fit.lognormal)

fit.weibull <- fitdist(s_all_data, distr = "weibull", 
                       lower = c(0,0), start = list(scale = 1, shape = 1))
plot(fit.weibull)
```

As you can see I made some changes to the fit.weibull relative to the others (including lower = , start = ), because I read somewhere that it was necessary but I don't know why.
Only the fit.normal and fit.weibull code work now. The others all give errors.
If I'm correct I can find out what distributions is best by looking at the QQ-plots and by checking which fit has the lowest "aic" value. However I'm sure that the normal distribution can not be used as the P-value for the Shapiro-Wilk normality test was (should be larger than 0.05):

```
> shapiro.test(s_all_data)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  s_all_data
W = 0.84391, p-value = 1.017e-09
```

The normal and Weibull distributions have the following aic value:

```
> fit.normal$aic
[1] -862.8635
> fit.weibull$aic
[1] 5.753959
```

Is this the right way of analysing which distribution fits best? And how can I make the other distribution fits work?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, your data is the quotient of amount of plastics and area (a kind of concentration)? Each value represents one region? I don't understand why any of these distributions should be expected to fit this data. Can't you just plot the empirical cumulative distribution function, i.e., `plot(ecdf(s_all_data))`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The data consists of multiple measurement days in which the same segments were measured. It has unit #plastic/m^2. I want to create a probability density graph from which a smoother cumulative frequency graph can be made. From this cumulative frequency graph I can easily extract the values for the different percentiles that will be used to make the classification system.

Comment: Can you explain why you can't extract the percentiles from the ECDF?

Comment: That is possible and I already did that as a first approximation. What I need now is a probability function, form which I can make another smoother CDF in which the graph depends on the probability function.

Comment: Using this method outliers in the data will be off less importance when determining the percentiles.

Comment: Well, I don't see how enforcing a distribution model that has no theoretical justification could be a good approach. Maybe you could focus on kernel density estimates where you can tune the bandwidth. However, I would consider your "outliers" the most important values in the dataset. Removing their impact by fitting some arbitrary distribution model seems like a bad approach.

Comment: Why enforce? What is wrong about gathering data at a certain place and then analyse how it is distributed? \